# UPDATE-FROM SQLite statement doesn't work in Node JS

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, sql-update, datagrip

I am developing a small program using Electron JS and I use SQLite as a database engine with the help of `sqlite3` module in Node JS. On the click event of a button in the program I update the database using [`UPDATE FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) statement. However, when I run the program and click the button, I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "FROM": syntax error
--> in Database#run('\n' +
  '        UPDATE StorageProducts\n' +
  'SET quantity = StorageProducts.quantity - innerquery.q2 * innerquery.c\n' +
  'FROM(select SP.quantity as q1, RP.quantity as q2, PHS.consumes as c, SP.product_name as product_name\n' +
  '        FROM StorageProducts SP\n' +
  '         INNER JOIN ProductHasStorage PHS on SP.product_name = PHS.storage_name\n' +
  '         INNER JOIN ReceiptProduct RP on PHS.product_name = RP.product_name\n' +
  'WHERE receipt_id = 2) AS innerquery\n' +
  'WHERE StorageProducts.product_name = innerquery.product_name\n' +
  '        ', [ 2 ], [Function])
```

Here is the statement I am trying to run using `db.run()`:

```
update StorageProducts
set quantity = StorageProducts.quantity - innerquery.q2 * innerquery.c
from(select SP.quantity as q1, RP.quantity as q2, PHS.consumes as c, SP.product_name as product_name
        from StorageProducts SP
         inner join ProductHasStorage PHS on SP.product_name = PHS.storage_name
         inner join ReceiptProduct RP on PHS.product_name = RP.product_name
where receipt_id = 1) as innerquery
where StorageProducts.product_name = innerquery.product_name
```

Another thing is that when I executed the very same statement in an external databases tool -[DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)-, It worked fine and updated the table as expected!

Comment: UPDATE FROM was added in sqlite 3.33. You're using an older version that doesn't understand that syntax.

Comment: @Shawn I noticed this in the documentation so I upgraded sqlite3 version which is built in on my mac. Now when write `sqlite` in my terminal, I get this: `SQLite version 3.34.0 2020-12-01 16:14:00`. May sqlite3 module in node use a different version from the one installed in the system?

Comment: It certainly could bundle its own copy of the sqlite library, yes.

Comment: @Shawn Okay, do you have any idea about how to know the version of sqlite used and how to change it, if possible?